# output list in bullet points

Tags: vba, excel

I would like this macro to output the list in bullet points without underline, with font size 18.  How do I do this?

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set ListStart = .Range("L13")

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pvt In sh.PivotTables



         .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ListStart.Offset(i, 0), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        pvt.TableRange2.Cells(1).Address(external:=True), TextToDisplay:=pvt.Name


                i = i + 1



        Next pvt
    Next sh
End With

ListStart.Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the character "•" in your cells.   `TextToDisplay = "• " & pvt.Name` or something like that.

As for changing the font size, `Cells.Font.Size = "18"` (I'll leave you to sort out the details) will do it.

There won't be underline unless you specify it, so that ought to be enough.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey thanks!, but where do i insert the " cell.font.size " statement?